# how to upload multipart/form-data with RNfetchblob in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

This is a code what i have tried make FormData looks fine.

But I'm not sure how to handle uri with data field, should i encode to base64 ?

```
  RNFetchBlob
    .fetch("POST",`${config.apiHost}/${path}`,{ 
        "Authorization" : token,
        "X-AUTH-SECURE" : secure,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
        [
          { name : String(payload.fileName),
            filename:payload.fileName,
            data :RNFetchBlob.wrap(payload.uri) }  
        ]
     )
     .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
         console.log("Upload", Math.floor(written/total * 100))
      })
     .then(response => {
         if(response.status===401){
               return;
         }
         console.log('The file upload ', response)
     }).catch(error=>{
         console.log(error);
     });
```

then I got response from console.log that is

```
"{"state":"error","code":0,"message":"internal server error","debug":"Error: Unexpected field\n    at makeError (C:\\ ... blah
```

how to solve this?

plus ) reference library : 
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

Comment: First `append()` takes at least two arguments, the first being the `name` of the value being set, and then the value, so `append('name','data')`. Second that error is from the server so whatever script ran from that request error'ed out, maybe due to your mistake from `append()`

Comment: @PatrickEvans you are right i had append('file','data'), but i deleted when i tested, anyway i just edited code adding 'file'. but still got same error..:/

Answer (score 0):

send the file in the following format

```
const filePath = filepathOriginal.replace('file://', '');
    const filename = filepathOriginal.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    [
      {
        name: 'multipartFile', filename, type: 'image/jpg', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath),
      },
    ]
```